# Maven install in modular project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I got a multi level maven project as follows;

```
Parent 
    Core (generate core jar)
            web-service (generate service jar)
                  web-app(generate WAR)
    ..
```

In Parent POM, I have define the modules as core,web-service and web-app.

In web-app module, I have dependencies for core.jar and service.jar.

Is there is a way to generate the war file in web-app through parent?
When I try to run mvn install in web-app. I get dependency issue with core.jar and web-service jar. which mean. I have to run mvn install in parent project first then run the mvn war:war in web-app project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run maven commands in the child directory it won't know about sibling or parent dependencies. I find it easiest to run the maven commands in the outermost parent root directory with multi module projects. If you just want to build some descendent project (let's call it `foo`) then from the parent you can do:

```
mvn install -pl :foo -am
```

Where the `pl` flag is a list of artifacts you want to build and the `am` flag means also build their dependencies.

Comment: At the moment, I run install in parent level, then run war:war in web-app level. so I can use something similar to 

        `mvn install -pl :foo -am`

to install the generate war at web-app level?

Comment: Yes if I understand right. Simply change foo to the artifactId for the web app and run it from the parent Pom directory

Comment: if I run `install -pl :foo -am` parent level, its install all the jar for `foo` and its dependencies, now how do I create the WAR file same time? I only got war target at `foo` project?

Comment: If your pom file is correctly configured the war is created within the package phase automatically ? If not your build is wrong..But without showing your pom files it's impossible to say how it is ?